# Need to melt DataFrame using timedelta and add column with a date

Tags: python, pandas

I have done the opposite of this many times with groupby and pd.pivot_table, and have been successful in using pd.melt but do not know if this is the case for that and how to weave in the datetime component.

original DF:

```
Location  Week Starting  Allotment
A         8/01/2022       700
A         8/15/2022       700
A         8/22/2022       700
B         8/01/2022       700
B         8/15/2022       700 
B         8/20/2022       700
```

Needed Output:

```
Location  Week Starting    Day         Day Allotment
A          8/01/2022      8/01/2022     df['Allotment']/7
A          8/01/2022      8/02/2022     df['Allotment']/7 
A          8/01/2022      8/03/2022     df['Allotment']/7 
A          8/01/2022      8/04/2022     df['Allotment']/7
A          8/01/2022      8/05/2022     df['Allotment']/7
A          8/01/2022      8/06/2022     df['Allotment']/7
A          8/01/2022      8/06/2022     df['Allotment']/7
```

and so on for the rest of the locations

Comment: can you post entire output for atleast the group A?

Answer (score 0):

You want to upsample, for this you can create all the dates and `explode`:

```
out = (df
   .assign(Day=[pd.date_range(d, periods=7, freq='D')
                for d in df['Week Starting']],
           Allotment=df['Allotment'].div(7)
          )
   .explode('Day')
)
```

output (first 10 rows):

```
  Location Week Starting  Allotment        Day
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-01
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-02
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-03
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-04
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-05
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-06
0        A     8/01/2022      100.0 2022-08-07
1        A     8/15/2022      100.0 2022-08-15
1        A     8/15/2022      100.0 2022-08-16
1        A     8/15/2022      100.0 2022-08-17
...
```

Alternative using reindexing:

```
df['Week Starting'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week Starting'])

(df
 .assign(Allotment=df['Allotment'].div(7))
 .set_index(['Location', 'Week Starting'])
 .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Location'].unique(),
                                      pd.date_range(df['Week Starting'].min(),
                                                    df['Week Starting'].max()+pd.Timedelta('7D')
                                                   )
                                     ], names=['Location', 'Week Starting']))
 .ffill().reset_index()
)
```